# Transition between controllers is jumpy

Tags: ios, swift

I have some small black flickering in the transition moment between controllers.
I have to load many things to the new controller before I show it, and I pass it some `UIImage` argument called "Art".

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller:ModelController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModController") as! ModelController
controller.artwork=art //pass this to load the new

let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.30
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

On the new controller, I load everything after :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //load scroller here
```

Comment: did you try not loading anything in destination view controller? do you have any gif of what do you mean by "jumpy"?

Comment: I will try to make one. thank you.